# KendoGrid: How to calculate number of rows depending on grid height?

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a window that can be resized by the user, so the height is variable. Depending on this height, I'd like to set the number of rows per page. How can this be calculated?

Comment: Aren't the row heights going to vary based on content?  For example a very long street address might wrap on to two lines.

Comment: you're right, in this case any long fields would be truncated, otherwise it wouldn't work.